# Javascript - Sumar valores input de un div, ignorando el otro div

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de sumar los valores de los input del div **derecha**, ignorando los valores del div izquierda...

**[VER DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wkj9x6f1/14/)**

El asunto es que no me sale. El script me suma todos los inputs, estén donde estén.

¿Alguna idea de cómo indicarle al script que **ignore el div izquierda**...?

Muchas gracias...

```
<div id="izquierda">
  <input name="qty1" value="240">
  <input name="qty2" value="862">
  <input name="qty3" value="911">
  <input name="qty4" value="">
  <input name="qty5" value="">
  <input name="qty6" value="">
  <input name="qty7" value="">
  <input name="qty8" value="">
</div>

<!-- ================ -->

<div id="derecha">
  <input name="qty1" value="2">
  <input name="qty2" value="2">
  <input name="qty3" value="2">
  <input name="qty4" value="">
  <input name="qty5" value="">
  <input name="qty6" value="">
  <input name="qty7" value="">
  <input name="qty8" value="">
</div>

<!-- ================ -->

<div id="cont-resultado">
<input name="total" id="total">
<a href="javascript:sumInputs()">Ver total</a>
</div>
```

---

```
window.sumInputs = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        result = document.getElementById('total'),
        sumar = 0;            

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        var ip = inputs[i];

        if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
            sumar += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
        }
    }

    result.value = sumar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var valores = $('#derecha').children();

var suma = 0;
$.each(valores,function(){
  valor = $(this).val() || 0;
  suma += parseInt( valor );
});

console.log(suma);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="izquierda">
  <input name="qty1" value="240">
  <input name="qty2" value="862">
  <input name="qty3" value="911">
  <input name="qty4" value="">
  <input name="qty5" value="">
  <input name="qty6" value="">
  <input name="qty7" value="">
  <input name="qty8" value="">
</div>

<!-- ================ -->

<div id="derecha">
  <input name="qty1" value="2">
  <input name="qty2" value="2">
  <input name="qty3" value="2">
  <input name="qty4" value="">
  <input name="qty5" value="">
  <input name="qty6" value="">
  <input name="qty7" value="">
  <input name="qty8" value="">
</div>

<!-- ================ -->
```

Tienes que hacer referencia unicamente al div de la derecha. En tu codigo, fijate que estás recogiendo todos los inputs

```
getElementsByTagName('input')
```

y por eso te está sumando todos los valores.

Te dejo aquí el código en jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var valores = $('#derecha').children();

var suma = 0;
$.each(valores,function(){
  valor = $(this).val() || 0;
  suma += parseInt( valor );
});
console.log(suma);  
});
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:

Te dejo [aquí el ejemplo de fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e4g8hvd/) que me has puesto. 
Simplemente he puesto el codigo que te proponia al principio de mi respuesta y lo he puesto en una función que he llamado "sumar()". Entonces, ejecutamos la función al principio de la carga de la página (para que ya te sume los valores desde el principio) y he agregado un evento click sobre el link de "Ver total", donde he sustituido la llamada a la función que tenias (onclick) por la llamada a la función sumar.

He puesto también que el resultado se muestre en un span con id "suma-valores". 
Creo que lo verás bastante claro. De todas formas, si no es así, no te preocupes. Pregunta y lo vemos.

Espero que te haya servido. Un saludo!

Comment: tu respuesta parece maravillosa (muchas gracias), pero algo estoy haciendo mal en el script porque no puedo ver el resultado... VER LINK : http://jsfiddle.net/wkj9x6f1/18/

Comment: @Pablo_Web , basadome en el ejemplo que me pones de jsfiddle he modificado un poquito tu código. Échale un vistazo. Yo creo que lo verás a la primera.

Comment: No sé que pasará, pero no funciona. Igual muchas gracias, y he respondido mi propia pregunta. El resultado aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/puro8xke/ Echale un vistazo. Muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responderme a mi mismo, que con un poco de ayuda en otros sitios logré hacerlo, y puede resultar muy útil para otros usuarios:

**[VER DEMO AQUÍ](https://jsfiddle.net/puro8xke/)**

```
<div id="cont-resultado">
<input name="total" id="total">
<a id='sumup' href="#">See total</a>
<!--<a href="javascript:sumInputs()">See total</a>-->
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sumInputs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valores = $('#derecha').children('input');
    var suma = 0;
    $.each(valores, function() {
      valor = $(this).val();
      suma += Number(valor);
    });

    valores = document.getElementById('total');
    $(valores).val(suma);
  }

  $('#sumup').on('click', sumInputs);
});
```

Comment: Entendí mal entonces donde querías sacar el resultado. Si te fijas en mi ejemplo, lo muestro donde pone "El resultado de éste ejemplo debe ser =". Me alegro de que lo hayas podido hacer por ti mismo. Espero que lo hayas entendido todo bien. Un saludo!

Comment: Entiendo cooper. Igual estoy aprendiendo poco a poco. Creo que todos alguna vez pasamos por el principio desde cero... Muchas gracias por tu amable ayuda (y de todos los demás). Es gratificante aprender así... :) ... Un saludo!.